# Broken Links when using Tokens

Tags: sitecore-client, habitat

I have a Sitecore 8.1 multisite environment and when I scan for broken links all items that are using tokens are falsely reported as having broken links.

For example:

A datasource of an item is:

`$site/Components/Global/Header`

`$site` resolves to the site the user is on.

Is there any way to prevent these from showing in the broken links report?

Comment: I retagged your question; as $site is not a token in OOTB Sitecore; it is introduced in the Habitat demo solution.

Comment: Looked a little bit into your issue. It boils down to the ValidateLinks method on a field type (such as Sitecore.Data.Fields.RenderingDatasourceField). If there is a value the GetItem will try to fetch the item with $site/Components/Global/Header. Don't have a solution though

Comment: Not sure if it'll work, but try implementing the solution in this answer: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/9174/490

Answer (score 2):

It's not too easy to do for all fields at once, but I think you have a few options to choose from.

## Option 1 - Extend and replace existing fields with custom link validation

The broken/not broken logic is handled on each separate field type, so you can extend one (or several) of them and override the `ValidateLinks(LinkedsValidationResult)` method. You then also need to patch the field type in the configuration using a config patch file. This will also work in the Content Editor and no longer warn you about broken links when saving.

Here is an example for the **Rendering Datasource** field type:

```
using System.Linq;
using Sitecore.Data.Fields;
using Sitecore.Links;

namespace YourNamespace.Fields
{
    public class CustomRenderingDatasourceField : RenderingDatasourceField
    {
        public CustomRenderingDatasourceField(Field innerField)
            : base(innerField)
        {
        }

        public CustomRenderingDatasourceField(Field innerField, string runtimeValue)
            : base(innerField, runtimeValue)
        {
        }

        public override void ValidateLinks(LinksValidationResult result)
        {
            // Skip completely if path contains "$site"
            if (Path?.Contains("$site") ?? false)
                return;

            base.ValidateLinks(result);
        }
    }
}
```

You could maybe also try to replace the `$site` token, but I'm not 100% sure about contexts etc. so you will have to do some experimentation with that yourself.

Config patch to make the field use your custom implementation:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <fieldTypes>
      <fieldType name="Rendering Datasource" set:type="YourNamespace.Fields.CustomRenderingDatasourceField, YourAssembly" />
    </fieldTypes>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

## Option 2 - A custom field with its own link validation

You could also create a new custom field. You would then need to change the field type in all the places where you might end up using the `$site` token.

## Option 3 - Replace SqlServerLinkDatabase and filter broken links

This option is actually pretty simple, but also in a place I would prefer to not tinker with too much.

**NOTE**: I haven't actually tested this, but it should work.

Extend the class `Sitecore.Data.SqlServer.SqlServerLinkDatabase` and override the method `ItemLink[] GetBrokenLinks(Database)`.

In there call the method of the base class and then filter out unwanted broken links - in the example below, all links containing `$site`.

```
using Sitecore.Data.SqlServer;
using Sitecore.Data;
using Sitecore.Links;

public class CustomSqlServerLinkDatabase : SqlServerLinkDatabase
{
    public CustomSqlServerLinkDatabase(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
    }

    public override ItemLink[] GetBrokenLinks(Database database)
    {
        var brokenLinks = base.GetBrokenLinks(database).Where(x => !x.TargetPath.Contains("$site"));
        return brokenLinks.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Then you just replace the **LinkDatabase** with a config patch:

```
<configuration xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <LinkDatabase set:type="Your.Namespace.CustomSqlServerLinkDatabase, Your.Assembly" />
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

This will not change anything in the Content Editor regarding warnings when saving items with "broken" links.

Comment: RenderingDatasourceField is having an internal access specifier, so we are unable to consume it in SC9.1. Do we have any other base class, can be used or any other solution?