# RenderField pipeline not giving single and multi line field type

Tags: pipelines

I was trying to extend `RenderField` pipeline, I tried below, but still not getting single-line or multi-line Field TypeKey. I am using Sitecore 9.1 initial release is anything I am missing?

```
-Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetFieldValue
-Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetTextFieldValue
-Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetMemoFieldValue
```

Reference blog I followed

[Using custom tokens in Sitecore](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/9167/using-custom-tokens-in-sitecore)

[image: reference blog]

Answer (score 1):

I tried this approach to extend the functionality of the pipeline `Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetTextFieldValue`

1. Extracted the code from the DLL and created my custom class like below.

**TokenReplacer**

```
namespace CMS.Feature.Replacer
{
    public class TokenReplacer
    {
        public void Process(RenderFieldArgs args)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)args, nameof(args));
            this.EncodeFieldValue(args);
            string fieldTypeKey = args.FieldTypeKey;
            if (!fieldTypeKey.Equals("text", StringComparison.InvariantCulture) && !fieldTypeKey.Equals("single-line text", StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
                return;
            args.WebEditParameters.Add("prevent-line-break", "true");
        }

        protected virtual void EncodeFieldValue(RenderFieldArgs args)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)args, nameof(args));
            if (!Settings.Rendering.HtmlEncodedFieldTypes.Contains(args.FieldTypeKey))
                return;
            args.Result.FirstPart = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(args.Result.FirstPart);
        }
    }
}
```

2. Created a patch file and put it into the below location.

**wwwroot<solution-root-directory>\App_Config\Include\zzz\TokenReplacer.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:x="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>   
    <pipelines>
      <renderField>        
        <processor x:after="*[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetTextFieldValue, Sitecore.Kernel']" type="CMS.Feature.Replacer.TokenReplacer, CMS.Feature.Replacer" />
      </renderField>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

And I was able to get the single-line-text field type in my code.

[image]

And also the token like below.

[image]

Try this and update if you find any issue.

Comment: Hi @Sumit,
thanks for the quick answer. I tried again as you suggest, for me all rendering component rich text field comes up but not the single-line and multiline field.

Comment: @Singh Did you extend the same `Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetTextFieldValue` pipeline?

Comment: Yes @Sumit,But not working

Comment: @Singh I don't know what is missing with your code, But I have checked it with OOTB one and it worked for me. And I also attached the screenshots.